# Ifstream, how to read next line after facing a specific character

Tags: c++, split, ifstream

```
    (example.txt)
    Tommy:16:Male
    Sam:23:Female
```

I wanted to code in C++ that take a data from the text file using ifstream but not the entire line.
For example, the first column represent Name and I just want to take Name data.

Is there a way to split ":" this character, just like Java line.split(":").

Comment: Why aren't you using `string::find` and `string::substr` ?

Comment: Will this do? http://stackoverflow.com/a/236803/572332

Comment: scanf might also be what you need, but it is quite oldschool C.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
std::ifstream infile("example.txt");

std::string line;
while (std::getline(infile, line))
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss.str(line);
    std::string item;
    while (getline(ss, item, ':')) {
        std::cout << item << std::endl;
    }
}
```